# how to export Core Data to CSV

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data, export-to-csv

I will like to use `CHCSVParser` to export my Core data to CSV. I know how to get all the value from entity, but I don't know how to write to CSV.

Can anybody teach me how to write to CSV with `CHCSVParser`?

```
// Test listing all Infos from the store
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"NoteLog" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (NoteLog *noteInfo in fetchedObjects) {

    NSLog(@"Name: %@", noteInfo.city );
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", noteInfo.country);
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", noteInfo.datetime);
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", noteInfo.notelatitude);
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", noteInfo.notelongtitude);
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", noteInfo.state);
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", noteInfo.text);        
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `CHCSVWriter` has several methods for constructing CSV files:

`-writeField:` accepts an object and writes its -description (after being properly escaped) out to the CSV file. It will also write field seperator (,) if necessary. You may pass an empty string (@"") or nil to write an empty field.

`-writeFields:` accepts a comma-delimited and nil-terminated list of objects and sends each one to -writeField:.

`-writeLine` is used to terminate the current CSV line. If you do not invoke -writeLine, then all of your CSV fields will be on a single line.

`-writeLineOfFields:` accepts a comma-delimited and nil-terminated list of objects, sends each one to -writeField:, and then invokes -writeLine.

`-writeLineWithFields:` accepts an array of objects, sends each one to -writeField:, and then invokes -writeLine.

`-writeCommentLine:` accepts a string and writes it out to the file as a CSV-style comment.

In addition to writing to a file, `CHCSVWriter` can be initialized for writing directly to an `NSString`.

Something Like this should work for you.

```
CHCSVWriter *writer = [[CHCSVWriter alloc] initForWritingToString];

for (NoteLog *noteInfo in fetchedObjects) {

    [writer writeLineOfFields:noteInfo.city, noteInfo.country, noteInfo.datetime, noteInfo.notelatitude, noteInfo.notelongtitude, noteInfo.state, noteInfo.text, nil];     
}  

NSLog(@"My CSV File: %@",writer.stringValue);
```

Comment: hi Rayan,
Will you beable to give me an example ?
all i need is the to export all the data out and thats it

Comment: Added some code for your particular case. If you paste that in you should get a nice CSV output in your console. From there I trust you know how to put it in a file and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Glad to hear :) Happy coding.

Comment: hi i was trying your code but seems that "initForWritingToString" has been replaced in CHCSVParser.  can u help me out. I have the same issue

Comment: It no longer writes to a string. Now it only writes directly to a path. `initForWritingToCSVFile:(NSString *)path` So just give it a path where you'd like your CSV file saved. You could store it somewhere temporary and read it to a string using `stringWithContentsOfFile:` if you really need it in a string.

Answer (score 8):

The answer above seems to be deprecated, the author replaced the method with another it seem.
This worked for me, hope it helps:

```
NSOutputStream *stream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToMemory];
CHCSVWriter *writer = [[CHCSVWriter alloc] initWithOutputStream:stream encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding delimiter:','];

for (Type *instance in fetchedResults) {
    [writer writeLineOfFields:@[instance.propertyA, instance.B]];
}
[writer closeStream];

NSData *buffer = [stream propertyForKey:NSStreamDataWrittenToMemoryStreamKey];
NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:buffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: what is fetchedResults?

Comment: @LukeIrvin, an array of database entities. See the original post - NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

Comment: Any idea how to use `writeLineOfFields` with swift?