# Passing/Export core data database from one device to another

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to create an app which will store data locally using coredata. Then I want to share/export that data(from coredata) to be used by other devices using same app.

Is it possible to send a coredata from one device to another? Can I just copy the *.sqlite file and overwrite the coredata in the other device?

I saw this post *[how to export Core Data to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572172/how-to-export-core-data-to-csv)* that allow core data to be exported as csv, But what I'm trying to achieve is to pass core data itself.

Thank You!

Comment: Are you asking how to synchronize your data between devices?

Comment: Yes. But I want to do it locally, maybe using bluetooth or any peer to peer communication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:` of [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator/migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:) to save the store to a file.  Once you have the file you can copy it to the other devices.

Other solutions might include iCloud if you're wanting data synchronisation.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll research about it.

Answer (score 3):

This [blog post](https://oleb.net/blog/2018/03/core-data-sqlite-backup/) suggests a good way to export the database as one file. Besides using the `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:` method, it also creates a copy of the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` to keep the current database consistent, and disables the sqlite write ahead and log to reduce all database to just one file.

In the device receiving the *sqlite* file, the following worked fine for me:

1 - Save the URL of the persistent store (`persistentContainer.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.url`)

2 - Delete the current persistent store, calling `persistentStoreCoordinator.remove` on your store instance inside `persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores`

3 - Saving the new database in the URL of the old one, using `FileManager.default.replaceItem` with the URL saved on the first step and the received file.

4 - Call `persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore` to add the store to the list of stores that core data will manage.

Also, before executing this whole process it might be good to reset all contexts ([context.reset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506807-reset)) to ensure no reference was kept, and in my case I executed everything inside the `persistentStoreCoordinator.performAndWait` method to avoid concurrency problems.